# Tensor products $ f^∗(S\otimes T) = (f^∗S)\otimes (f^∗T) $ .

Tags: calculus, manifolds, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$,$W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let $f$ be a linear map,
define $f^*$ to be the adjoint of $f$.
If $S$,$T$ are tensors on $W$ show that $f^∗(S\otimes T) = (f^∗S)\otimes (f^∗T)$

What I have so far is:

$f^∗(S\otimes T)(v_1,...,v_{2k}) = (S\otimes T)(f(v_1),...,f(v_{2k}))
=S(f(v_1),...,f(v_k))T(f(v_{k+1}),...,f(v_{2k}))
=f^*S(v_1,...,v_k)f^*T(v_{k+1},...,v_{2k})$

I'm not sure what step to take next to make it a tensor product,
the textbook I'm using said its easy, but I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Note that the linear maps $f^*$ that take in the tensors $S, T and S\otimes T$ are not the same map. Also, what is meant by the adjoint here? Is there an inner product or is $f^* :V^* \rightarrow W^* $ derived from $f:V\rightarrow W$?

Comment: The last line you got is exactly equal to what you need, by the definition of tensor products.